# Loading items on scroll

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create a function which uses one item to trigger a series of events:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(window).scroll(function(){
      startSlideUp('.cardWrap', '.card');
    });

function startSlideUp(atTop, beVisible) {
  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ($(atTop).offset().top - $(window).height() 200 < wScroll) {
    $(beVisible).each(function (i) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(beVisible).eq(i).addClass('is-visible');
      }, 500 * i);
    });
  }
}

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jackmichael/6mb765wx/24/

Comment: And whats the problem/s or your question?

Comment: The class 'is-visible' isnt been added to each card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your logic but error is with this line:

```
if ($(atTop).offset().top - $(window).height() 200 < wScroll) {
```

replace it with

```
if ($(atTop).offset().top - $(window).height() < (200+wScroll)) {
```

It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on scroll now is-visible class will be added,

```
if ($(atTop).offset().top - $(window).height() 200 < wScroll) {
```

Change the above to

```
if ($(atTop).offset().top - $(window).height() < wScroll) {
```